# CdkDragDrop's cdkDragBoundary is not working

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have to be missing something very simple but after an hour of fighting with it, I think I need to ask for help.  I'm trying to follow the simple example given for setting a cdkDragBoundary on the Angular site.  cdkDrag works as expected but ignores the boundary.  I've checked package.json to make sure that all the dependencies are up to date, and I believe they are.  Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

https://spuzzler.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you give us the url to edit your stackblitz please ? An easy thing to miss is the dot before the boundary : `cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss a dot :) `cdkDragBoundary=".play-area"` instead of `cdkDragBoundary="play-area"`

Comment: It was the dot.  I am kicking myself....  I'll make sure on any future posts I share the edit URL.  Thank you for your help!